# Big O questions: general tree operations and relative complexity

Tags: tree, complexity-theory, big-o

This isn't actually homework, but I need to understand these concepts in the class.

> What is the worst-case Big-O performance for the insert, find and
>   remove operations in a general tree? Why is this so?

I have no idea how to approach that one, since there are no constrictions on general trees.

> Which grows faster, O(n^2*log(n)) or O(n^1.01)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(n<sup>2 log n</sup>) grows much much faster than O(n<sup>1.01</sup>). I am assuming the base of the logarithm is 2 as in case of many Tree algorithms.

For example consider the case when n=1024.

n<sup>2 log n</sup> = 1024 <sup>2 * log 1024</sup> =1024<sup>20</sup>=1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376.

Where as n<sup>1.01</sup>=1024<sup>1.01</sup>=1097.5